# C# : Class pointer override

Tags: c#, c++, class, memory, casting

Is there any way to force a `class` or `struct` in C# to point to a specific block of memory, as in a `MemoryStream` or an array of `byte`s? If so, is there also a way to call its constructor after casting? I realize that there is little *practicality* in this, and it's potentially *unsafe*; I'm just trying to understand the facets of the language.

Here is some demo C++ code of what I'm describing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

// Don't worry about the class definition... as the name implies, it's junk
class JunkClass
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;

public:
    JunkClass(int aVal, int bVal) : a(aVal), b(bVal) { }
    ~JunkClass() { }

    static void *operator new(size_t size, void *placement){ return placement; }
};
```

//..

```
// Assuming 32-bit integer and no padding
// This will be the memory where the class pointer is cast from
unsigned char pBytes[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

//..

```
int main(void)
{
    // The next two lines are what I want to do in C#
    JunkClass *pClass = (JunkClass *)pBytes; // Class pointer pointing to pBytes
    pClass = new(pBytes) JunkClass(0x44332211, 0x88776655); // Call its constructor using placement new operator

    // Verify bytes were set appropriately by the class
    // This should print 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 to the console
    unsigned char *p = pBytes;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        printf("%02X ", *(p++));

    // Call destructor
    pClass->~JunkClass();
    while (!_kbhit());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no". You cannot say C# to create an object in a specific place.
The long answer is "it depends on your purpose". If you just want your object to stay where it was created consider using `GCHandle.Alloc`. You can also search for "pinned objects"([SO question about pinned objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490912/what-are-pinned-objects)).
Also you can pin an array of objects and reuse it's elements like they are "allocated" in a specific place.