# C# fill array of struct with random data

Tags: c#, random, struct

For testing purposes, I want to do the following thing:

```
class ArrayOfStructWithRandomData<T> where T : struct {
  private T[] array;

  ArrayOfStructWithRandomData() {
    array = new T[1000000];
    InitializeArrayToRandomData();
  }
}
```

How could I implement InitializeArrayToRandomData() without using the 'unsafe' keyword?

One idea was to use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) * 1000000)` to allocate a chunk of unmanaged memory, then use `Marshal.Copy(Byte[], Int32, IntPtr, Int32)` to fill that memory with random data and then use something like

```
static T[] GetArrayFromNativePointer<T>(IntPtr unmanaged_memory, int length) {
  T[] result = new T[length];
  if (IntPtr.Size == 4) {
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

    // 32-bit system.
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++) {
      result[i] = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(unmanaged_memory, typeof(T));
      unmanaged_memory= new IntPtr(unmanaged_memory.ToInt32() + size);
    }
  } else {
    long size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

    // Probably 64-bit system.
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++) {
      result[i] = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(unmanaged_memory, typeof(T));
      unmanaged_memory= new IntPtr(array.ToInt64() + size);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: To what end? What type of testing requires you to create potentially invalid objects?

Comment: May be using reflection you could retrieve fields of `T` and fill them up with random values.

Comment: Performance tests in which I don't want the compiler to optimize things away because it sees that all the structs are default initialized for example.

Comment: I like using the Marshal methods in this instance.  I'm not sure why the PtrToStructure is inside the for loop.

Comment: The problem is, anything you do *is* going to be unsafe since there's no way to express via generics that the `struct` can only *contain* `struct` members. The first time you call this method with a `struct` containing a reference and initialize that reference to a random value, hilarity will ensue.

Comment: Damien: will hilarity ensue upon initialization or upon attempt to access the reference?

Comment: @jdweng: it's in the loop because I think I need to marshal each element of the array separately - or is there a Marshal method that marshals the entire array directly? It seems to me that works only for arrays of primitive types (through Marshal.Copy)

Comment: If you have a root class that contains an array of structures then the data is continuous in memory and can be copied with one instructions.

Comment: @jdweng how? in C# the array is always reference type, i.e. a pointer.

Comment: In your static method, `array` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to turn off optimization for a specific method or property you can use

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization | MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
```

which will prevent the compiler and later the JITter from optimizing or inlining that method. You are then able to proceed using the default values without the compiler eventually optimizing things.

Comment: The thing is, I still want optimizations (as it's performance tests). But I don't want any optimizations that would base on the fact that all my structs contents are default initialized.

Answer (score 0):

i'am not sure if that what you are searching for but you can use implicit operator in the struct that initialize it  just like this example :

```
public static implicit operator MyStruct(T[] value) {
    return new MyStruct() { structValue = value, Structlength = value.Length };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct Root
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 1000000)]
            Child[] children { get; set; }
        }
        struct Child
        {
            int property1 { get; set; }
            int property2 { get; set; }
            int property3 { get; set; }
            int property4 { get; set; }
            int property5 { get; set; }
            int property6 { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: How does this populate an array with random data?

Comment: This isn't about populating with random data since the posted code didn't do it.  It is about moving the data from unmanaged to managed.  I'm just recommending eliminating the for loops in the posted code.

Comment: The right way to do that is to pin the array using `GCHandle.Alloc(arr, GCHandleType.Pinned` and then `AddrOfPinnedObject` and then `Marshal.Copy`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to copy from unmanaged memory into a managed array, the most effective way is to pin the array and copy using `Marshal.Copy`.

```
void BlitFromByteArrayToArray(byte[] src, T[] dst)
{
    Debug.Assert(src.Length == dst.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)));

    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(dst, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
        Marshal.Copy(src, 0, handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), src.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        handle.Free();
    }
}
```

Note that rather than allocating unmanaged memory, and then filling that unmanaged memory with random data, I've coded this with a byte array to hold the source random data. There's no need to use unmanaged memory for this.

Note that this entire approach does rather assume that `T` is a blittable type.

Finally, if efficiency matters, it would be better to do the following:

1. Allocate your managed array.
2. Pin the array using `GCHandle.Alloc`.
3. Write random data into the unmanaged array returned by `AddrOfPinnedObject`.
4. Unpin the array.

This would avoid needing to write to one buffer and then copy to another.

Comment: David : isn't the Marshal.Alloc putting the structure in unmanaged memory?  All pin does is stops the garbage collection from disposing the memory.

Comment: @jdweng There is no `Marshal.Alloc` here

Comment: Ok, but it is still unmanaged :GCHandle Provides a way to access a managed object from unmanaged memory.

Comment: @jdweng Pinning does not make the memory unmanaged. It simply stops the GC from moving the memory (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490912/what-are-pinned-objects).  It is still managed memory. You are wrong when you say that pinning just prevents GC collection. That's already prevented by the fact that we have references to the object.