# What are the use cases of the newly proposed Pin type?

Tags: rust, reference, rust-pin

There is a new `Pin` type in unstable Rust and the [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2349-pin.md) is already merged. It is said to be kind of a game changer when it comes to passing references, but I am not sure how and when one should use it.

Can anyone explain it in layman's terms?

Comment: Was something unclear about the [motivation listed in the RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2349-pin.md#motivation)?

Answer (score 15):

## What is pinning ?

In programming, pinning X means instructing X not to move.

For example:

- Pinning a thread to a CPU core, to ensure it always executes on the same CPU,
- Pinning an object in memory, to prevent a Garbage Collector to move it ([in C# for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490912/what-are-pinned-objects)).

## What is the `Pin` type about?

The [`Pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/mem/struct.Pin.html) type's purpose is to pin an object in memory.

It enables taking the address of an object and having a guarantee that this address will remain valid for as long as the instance of `Pin` is alive.

## What are the usecases?

The primary usecase, for which it was developed, is supporting *Generators*.

The idea of generators is to write a simple function, with `yield`, and have the compiler automatically translate this function into a state machine. The state that the generator carries around is the "stack" variables that need to be preserved from one invocation to another.

The key difficulty of Generators that `Pin` is designed to fix is that Generators may end up storing a reference to one of their own data members (after all, you can create references to stack values) or a reference to an object ultimately owned by their own data members (for example, a `&T` obtained from a `Box<T>`).

This is a subcase of self-referential structs, which until now required custom libraries (and lots of `unsafe`). The problem of self-referential structs is that if the struct move, the reference it contains still points to the *old* memory.

`Pin` apparently solves this years-old issue of Rust. As a library type. It creates the extra guarantee that as long as `Pin` exist the pinned value cannot be moved.

The usage, therefore, is to first create the struct you need, return it/move it at will, and then when you are satisfied with its place in memory initialize the pinned references.

Comment: Nice. thank you. But can we use it in simple data structures like queue OR tree or something? just want to expand my knowledge around the Pin type.

Comment: @00imvj00: If you mean to *implement* queue or trees, it has been pointed out that `Pin` could enable safe *intrusive* data-structures. Those are very specific structures, though. For general data-structures, I do not see a usecase yet... but since it's new, it may just be me being unimaginative.

Answer (score 5):

One of the possible uses of the `Pin` type is self-referencing objects; [an article by ralfj](https://www.ralfj.de/blog/2018/04/05/a-formal-look-at-pinning.html) provides an example of a `SelfReferential` struct [which would be very complicated without it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct):

```
use std::ptr;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::marker::PhantomPinned;

struct SelfReferential {
    data: i32,
    self_ref: *const i32,
    _pin: PhantomPinned,
}

impl SelfReferential {
    fn new() -> SelfReferential {
        SelfReferential { data: 42, self_ref: ptr::null(), _pin: PhantomPinned  }
    }

    fn init(self: Pin<&mut Self>) {
        let this : &mut Self = unsafe { self.get_unchecked_mut() };
        // Set up self_ref to point to this.data.
        this.self_ref = &mut this.data as *const i32;
    }

    fn read_ref(self: Pin<&Self>) -> Option<i32> {
        // Dereference self_ref if it is non-NULL.
        Some(unsafe { self.self_ref.as_ref().copied() })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data: Pin<Box<SelfReferential>> = Box::pin(SelfReferential::new());
    data.as_mut().init();
    println!("{:?}", data.as_ref().read_ref()); // prints Some(42)
}
```